# Space between when 1 row, and center elements when they are 2 rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I'm developing a nav bar and there are 2 elements. The logo on the left, and the list of actions on the right (this element has a dynamic number of elements).

When they can fit on one row, I want them to do so.

However, when they can no longer fit on 1 row, I want them to be placed on separate rows, and then centered. Like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.logo {
  background-color: red;
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="action-1">action 1</div>
    <div class="action-2">action 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? And if so, would it use grid or flexbox?

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS has no concept of the number of rows (certainly not yet, though that's requested feature of the language); so this will almost certainly require JavaScript; is that acceptable to you? Further, is it required for the `<div>` elements to be contained within a `div.actions` element?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily required they be contained within the actions div, no.

Comment: The solution probably lies in JS and/or media queries.

Answer (score 0):

We could add an extra `div` for the `logo` and another for the `actions` that way we can control them separately too. Those extra `div`s are going to take 50% each, which will allow you to set a specific `width` for the `logo` or `actions` and maintain the alignment.

Note: added the `outline` as well as the `width` (200px) to better visualize the extra `div`s in the example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
}

.div1 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}

.div2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="action-1">action 1</div>
      <div class="action-2">action 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They don't seem to break onto two lines when they get squished together?

Comment: try again, the do squish together